# Problems joining domain server 2008

Tags: active-directory

Ok here goes. am sort of new to this so be nice.

We have a windows server 2008 on a site, lets call this Site A.

we ran up a new windows 2008 server at site A - install > dcpromo > join existing domain > specified domain to join e.g abc.local > all went well.

We then ran up a second server and took it to site B and ran DCPROMO same as above but the domain was not found.

we can access the server on site A via it's IP address but not it's server name as required by dcpromo.

At this point I think DNS.

I install DNS role on new server at site B and this is where I start to fumble around in the dark a little.

So I try New > forward lookup > Secondary zone > enter the IP of main server on site A click out of the box and the wizard shows the server name and a tick to say its verified, I then finish the wizrd.

When I browse the new zone there has been an error and a message says that it was not copied from the master.

And I am stuck.

Tech desk say's take the server back to site > DCPROMO > join domain then they get a bit fuzzy with the details and suggest sites and services and add subnets?  erm Lo

Answer (score 4):

Edit the interface properties on your server you're trying to dcpromo. Point the DNS server an existing DC that hosts DNS, not itself. Once you've DCPromo'd and everything has replicated properly, you can point it back to itself.

Comment: Yep, to join a domain (either for servers doing a dcpromo or ordinary endusers machines), the primary DNS server on the local machine should point to the domain controller. It's a Mickeysoft thing :-)

Comment: +1 - Get the machine joined to the domain / DCPROMO'd first, allow replication to occur, and you'll find that the local DNS server will "magically" be populated with the AD-integrated DNS zones.

Comment: Ok so I take the server back to Site A, run dcpromo which will install and configure DNS for me.  Then take the server to its new home on site B and all should be good?

Comment: Well...yes and no...yes that would work...but no you don't need to do it that way. As long as your VPN is setup correctly, you should be able to leave the server at site B and just reconfigure the DNS settings for the interface. After the server is dcpromo'd, change the DNS settings back.

Comment: Oh...and sites and services...you'll want to set that up...eventually...not now...get the server dcpromo'd first...Then mess with S&S...it wouldn't effect what you're experiencing right now.